# A row for each column as MySQL select result

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following columns:

```
 x y z col1 col2 col3 ... col12
```

As a select result I want a row for each colX column. So this will result in 12 rows for each row:

```
 x y z col1
 x y z col2
 x y z col3
 ...
 x y z col12
```

Is this possible in MySQL and how should I start on this?

Comment: Converting columns into rows is called unpivot, the duplicate shows a few different ways to get the result.

Comment: see here http://courses.oreillyschool.com/dba1/dba110.html